# JavaScript using bind function in IE11 gives Object doesn't support this action

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ecmascript-6, babel-polyfill

I have a JavaScript code that is using events to communicate between different components. I am using `ES6` syntax and **webpack**. I am also using `babel-polyfill` for the dumb Microsoft IE 11!

I have a line like this (my `timeline_` variable is an instance of [vis.js Timeline](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/index.html):

```
this.timeline_.on('rangechange', this._handleTimelineMove.bind(this));
```

In Chrome (and Edge), everything is working fine, but in IE the `bind` function doesn't seem to work. If I put a break-point on this line and use the Watch window to run this:

```
this._handleTimelineMove.bind(this)
```

it gives me this:

[image: Object doesn't support this action]

In Chrome, it gives me this:

[image]

which is the actual function that needs to be called back when the event happens.

When I do the `typeof` in IE and Chrome, both give back `"function"`, but I don't understand the behavior of IE!

I also tried including `es5-shim` and `es6-shim` packages, but to no avail.

Thank you in advance

## EDIT

It turned out that the problem was somewhere else in the code. I was creating a `MouseEvent` in my code that IE doesn't support (why should it?!), and that was somehow the source of the problem, not the `bind` method. I just found the issue by pure luck!

Comment: The different console output should not concern you. It's just different representations in different contexts.

Comment: Wait, so you say when you enter it manually it works but when called from the script it throws? What exactly is the error, and where is it thrown (when calling `.bind()`, or when calling the bound function)?

Comment: The "bound" function is supposed to be passed as a callback to the `on` function, so that it will be called when `rangechange` event is raised. But in IE, it seems that the callback function doesn't contain the code that it should contain! If you look at the screenshot for IE, you see that it is
`function() { [native code] }`, but it shouldn't! It should contain the code contained in the function

Comment: No, it should not. A bound function *is* a native object (containing some internal references to the original function). I'm not sure where Chrome got the function code from, and why it doesn't show that is has bound parameters and context.

Comment: But what is that message: `TypeError: Object doesn't support this action` in IE?

Comment: Given that it shows up in the inspector only, I guess that the engine does not support evaluating the `.arguments` or `.caller` properties of a bound function during the break point halt - or that simply accessing the property throws, as is proper for strict mode functions.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Is there a way to overcome this? Because it doesn't seem to be only an issue during the investigation of the breakpoint. When the callback function is called, in the "Console" of the developer tools, I see errors saying `TypeError: Object doesn't support this action`

Comment: What exactly is throwing these errors? (that's a horribly generic error message :-/)

Comment: @Bergi thank you for your help. You were right about the fact that the bound function should not contain the function code (I think Chrome is trying to be nice and display the code that will be executed). In my case, the problem was in a totally different place in my code: I was creating a `MouseEvent` somewhere in the code, which IE doesn't support (of course!), and that was causing the issue. I just found it by pure luck!